# Debug vs release library version has different behavior with debug/release client application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dynamic, dll

I have library (dynamic with implicit linking) built by msvc 10.0, that exports classes and STL containers. It built as release and as debug (two versions). It is not mine, so I don't have source code.

I have simple application, that calls methods from this library (built also by msvc 10.0, so, I guess, there shouldn't be problems with compatibility of STL and compiler versions).

- If application built as debug links debug version of library - everything works, as suppose to.
- If application built as release links release version of library - everything works, as suppose to.
- If application built as debug links release version of library - there appears mistakes inside library logic, it throws exception **length_error** with text **"vector too long”**

Why can that happens, if it perfectly works without any changing, just if application has different release/debug settings?

I didn't changed any default IDE settings, choosing "release"/"debug".

Comment: Mixing build-types is never a good idea.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes we don't have debug library versions. But we have to debug our application, and build it as "debug". And I never met such problems. If you could advice where can be problem, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Debug and release versions of classes and STL containers can have different memory layouts, including different variables. Code that is compiled assuming one layout will fail if it is asked to process the other layout.

Comment: Why would they have different memory layout, if they both use same compiler and same STL realization?

Comment: As I understand debugging - it's like additional layout / memory manager that generates some debug info about allocated memory every time it allocate it. And creating methods to access that allocated memory, but not change logic of any method it wrapped.